# What is the loop order of bmesh faces?

Tags: scripting, bmesh

Let's suppose I create a bmesh with the following commands:

```
import bmesh
bm = bmesh.new()
bm.from_mesh(obj.data)
bmesh.ops.triangulate(bm, faces=bm.faces)
```

Have a look at the following picture to get to know what counterclockwise (**CCW**) and clockwise (**CW**) indexing means:

[image: CCW vs CW]

Now when I iterate over the meshes faces after triangulating it is there any indication/standard in what order (**CCW** or **CW**) relative to the faces front/normal I will iterate over the loops of each face?
Is it safe to assume that I will the following script will either always output [1,2,3] or [3,2,1] for a triangle like seen above?

```
l = []
for face in bm.faces:
    for loop in face.loops:
        l.append(loop.vert.index)
assert l==[1,2,3] // Or [3,2,1], or one of those lists rotated
```

PS: Can anyone propose a nice solution that will always guarantee CCW indexing for the faces loops?

Comment: I'm sure someone who knows all this stuff will come along to help with this but for now I can point you to a tool that will help you see the results of your tinkering.  http://wiki.blender.org/index.php/Extensions:2.6/Py/Scripts/3D_interaction/Index_Visualiser

Comment: You should check out the bmesh design document: http://wiki.blender.org/index.php/Dev:2.6/Source/Modeling/BMesh/Design

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From https://wiki.blender.org/wiki/Source/Modeling/BMesh/Design:

> Loops store several handy pointers:
>
> - v - pointer to the vertex at the start of the edge (where "start" is defined by CCW order)

this means that CCW indexing can be assumed if I don't get it wrong. Also note that the loop-list on the face is circular according to this:

> Faces link to a loop in the loop cycle, the circular linked list of loops defining the boundary of the face.